# Is forecasting appropriate for a seemingly random time-series?

Tags: time-series

Here's the problem : Each day, a number of virtual machines are created by users. I would like to forecast one day ahead how many virtual machines will be created during the next day. 
I have at my disposal a time-series representing the number of virtual machines created each day.

[Time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrlGG.png)

I cannot notice any particular trend, seasonality or correlation in this time-series, so I would like some advice on whether I should drop the idea of forecasting completely or if there is a forecasting model out there that could work well with my data.

Comment: Check if the time series is white noise,  if it is then it's truly just made up of a random component

Comment: You can easily infer that the next day $7\pm 2$ machines will be created. As this is a statistic problem you will never be able to know what is the exact number.